# Multiple databases support in Symfony

Tags: symfony1

I am using Propel as my DAL for my Symfony project. I can't seem to get my application to work across two or more databases.

Here's my schema.yml:

```
db1:
  lkp_User:
    pk_User:                     { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
    UserName:                    { type: varchar(45), required: true }
    Password:                    longvarchar
    _uniques:
      Unique:                    [ UserName ]

db2:
  tesco:
    Id:                  { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
    Name:                { type: varchar(45), required: true }
    Description:         longvarchar
```

And here's the databases.yml:

```
dev:
  db1:
    param:
      classname: DebugPDO
test:
  db1:
    param:
      classname: DebugPDO
all:
  db1:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      dsn: 'mysql:dbname=bpodb;host=localhost'   #where the db is located
      username: root
      password: #pass
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true


  db2:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      dsn: 'mysql:dbname=mystore2;host=localhost'   #where the db is located
      username: root
      password: #pass
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true
```

When I call `php symfony propel-build-model`, only `db1` is generated, `db2` is not.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I got this issue working](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-configure-multiple-databases-for.html)! The most important thing is you must name your schema according to %dbname%.schema.yml. In this way Symfony will be able to assign the ymls to the correct database.

Answer (score 1):

Also when running the task you should specify the connection for example:

```
symfony propel:build-all-load --connection=my_connection
```

This worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Propel::getConnection('db2')` to manually retrieve a connection.

Just have in mind that what you call "db1", "db2" are the *connection names*. You can have several connections to a same database with various login/permissions (like read only etc.).

It's very good for testing purpose: you can do it with the same connection name with a different database. No way to crash your production database with that :)