# how to use multiple database in symfony

Tags: database, symfony1

I'm creating a project in symfony, but suddenly I'm having trouble when there are two databases for my project like this:

```
all:  gapi_1:
class: sfDoctrineDatabase
param:
  dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gapi_1
  username: root
  password:

 gapi_2:
class: sfDoctrineDatabase
param:
  dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gapi_2
  username: root
  password:
```

I'm very confused about how to access database in my action pages. Please help me to access the symfony multiple database in same action.class.php file.

Comment: did you have a look at the answer given in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733224/multiple-databases-support-in-symfony?

Comment: thanks for solution link, my database is created successfully but i unable to access them. So, please help me to access this database in action.class.php

Answer (score 0):

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setCurrentConnection('gapi_1');
```

and

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setCurrentConnection('gapi_2');
```

outside of the context i think like that (not sure):

```
$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
$db1 = $databaseManager->getDatabase('gapi_1');
$db1->getDoctrineConnection();
```